# How do I web scrape a dynamic website in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from the following [website](https://toandthrough.uchicago.edu/tool/cps/comm/2021/school/77/details/#/hs-graduation) using R.

In particular, I want to grab the graduation rate data from this timeline.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I try to use SelectorGadget to find the right HTML nodes to pull the data with `rvest` I don't get any results. Likewise, I can't find the API endpoint using the developing tools.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Another document is requested. Check those in XHR requests. Then change URI fed to `rvest` and choose a suitably robust, yet performant, CSS selector list to mitigate script breakage if page HTML changes.

---

```r
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://toandthrough.uchicago.edu/tool/cps/comm/2021/school/77/$details?page=hs-graduation"

doc <- read_html(url)

doc %>%
  html_elements("#across-years .label-total text") %>%
  html_text2()
```